# What's causing this "window-relative" image cut off?

Tags: html, css, image

Look at the image below, and you'll see that part of one image is cut off.

#### Details

If you take a look at my HTML/CSS, you'll notice something strange upon resizing the page. It cuts off one image at a time, always the same distance from the top of the window. I've narrowed one part of the problem, which seems to lie in the last piece of the CSS (`margin-bottom:-35.35%`). Changing that value will change how the "set1" images get cut off in relation to the "mag1" images. I'm using Safari, and everything works how it should in Dreamweaver Live View. It only gives this error in the browser.

I have no clue what is causing this problem. Please help!

[image]

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="tester.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="pic1"><img id="set1" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/nv64aq.png"><a href="magazine cover.jpg"><img id="mag1" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/1tndhc.png"></a></div>
  <div id="pic2"><img id="set2" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2n87k3t.png"><a href="magazine cover.jpg"><img id="mag2" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/zixi8j.png"></a></div>
  <div id="pic3"><img id="set3" src="http://i59.tinypic.com/30204fb.png"><a href="magazine cover.jpg"><img id="mag3" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/25f0lyv.png"></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#pic1 {
    margin-top: 8%;
}
#pic1, #pic2, #pic3 {
    float: right;
    width: 68%;
    margin-left: 6%;
    margin-right: 6%;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
    position:relative;
}
#pic1 {
    z-index:2;
}
#pic2 {
    z-index:1;
}
#pic3 {
    margin-bottom:0;
}
#mag1, #set1, #mag2, #set2, #mag3, #set3 {
    width: 100%;
}
#set1,#set2,#set3 {
    margin-bottom:-35.35%;
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue, what browser are you using? can you provide a link?

Comment: It's Safari Version 7.1.5 on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: I just tested the HTML & CSS I just posted to make sure nothing was wrong. It still has the same exact problem.

Comment: could it have to do with a browser setting?